# Openrewrite systemouttologging recipe not working

Tags: openrewrite

https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/logging/systemouttologging

I am trying to apply the follwing recipe on a gradle project, but the recipe doesnt apply changes to my files.

Here is the build.gradle file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI7DB.png)
Here is my java class,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJgTW.png)

I am running the gradle using ./gradlew rewriterun.
Do I need to specify the options there? Can you please tell me if I miss something.

Not able to see the changes that recipe make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recipe is not making any changes, as you are missing a configuration option. Please also see the comment I had posted here two weeks ago: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-logging-frameworks/issues/110#issuecomment-1624308853

> There are no required options [as per the documentation](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/logging/systemouttologging), but when `addLogger` is not defined, then [no logging statements are inserted](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-logging-frameworks/blob/1929e7641da532643df6f5baec55b8ead6a620d3/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/java/logging/SystemOutToLogging.java#L117-L122) it seems. You might want to try again while [passing those options in a rewrite.yml file](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/yaml-format-reference). If that also fails for you, then it might be time to start on [a reproduction test](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-logging-frameworks/blob/main/src/test/java/org/openrewrite/java/logging/SystemOutToLoggingTest.java).

You might want to add a `rewrite.yml` file to your project root that passes in the required options.

```yaml
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: io.moderne.builder.YourRecipe
displayName: Your recipe
description: Created in the builder at https://app.moderne.io/recipes/builder
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.java.logging.SystemOutToLogging:
      addLogger: "True"
      loggingFramework: SLF4J
      level: info
```

Comment: io.moderne.builder.YourRecipe -> should be specified under sctive recipies sections in build.gradle file